# Facebook App - Get total user count

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have created the facebook app. I would like to the show the total number of users who are using my app. How can i get the total number of app users?

Note: using javascript or php sdk

Comment: total amount of online users on the app ?
or total of users registered to your app ?

Comment: thanks. i want registered users count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at Facebook graph API documentation :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/

example :

> https://graph.facebook.com/2439131959
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR-APP-ID/insights/application_active_users?since=1329724800&until=1329984000